# UITableView delays for 20 to 50 seconds after cellForRowAtIndexPath is called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I get a very long delay showing my table after `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `willDisplayCell` functions are called. I make sure that I call `reloadData` from main thread. I only show 10 rows. The delay is from 20 to 50 seconds. Here is some of the code:

Calling `reloadData` from the main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
[UIView animateWithDuration:0 animations:^{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    NSLog(@"AFTER RELOAD DATA=%lu", (unsigned long)self.tableView.visibleCells.count);
    //Do something after that...
}];
```

Here is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function:

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
IPEquipmentCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:IPEquipmentCell.CELL_ID forIndexPath:indexPath];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[IPEquipmentCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:IPEquipmentCell.CELL_ID];
}
IPEquipment *equip = self.equipmentResults[indexPath.row];
if ([@"Y" isEqualToString:equip.checkedIn]) {
    cell.checkmarkLabel.hidden = NO;
} else {
    cell.checkmarkLabel.hidden = YES;
}

cell.descriptionLabel.text = equip.descrip;
cell.equipIdLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ID: %@", equip._id];
cell.serialIdLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Serial/VIN: %@", equip.serial];
cell.ipTrackingLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"IP Tracking: %@", equip.ipTracking];
cell.sellerAssetLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Seller Asset: %@", equip.sellerAsset];

NSLog(@"cellForRowAtIndexPath=%@", equip);
return cell;
```

Here is my `willDisplayCell` function:

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.contentView.hidden = NO;
    NSLog(@"willDisplayCell=%@", indexPath);
}
```

I have gone through the debugger and stepped through the code and it seems like execution is finished and delay happens afterwards. Could you please help?

Comment: why did u put reload data in an animation block with 0 sec duration ?

Comment: I was trying for 0 delay for animations. I have tries this without this with same results.

Comment: It is better without it. Where did u put this code ?viewDidLoad shud be fine.

Comment: This is being called from the completion block where I get the data from the server through NSURLSessionDataTasks dataTaskWithRequest function. I call reloadData when I get the data into the array.

Comment: So when the completion block calls this code , does it take 20-50 seconds from that point?

Comment: it takes 20-50 seconds after the last willDisplayCell=%@ is printed.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Loading a table view is done asynchronously, so any ordering you expect is wrong anyway.  Does it matter why the completion is called 20 seconds later?

Comment: I am trying to load and show the data immediatly. It just has a delay of 20-50 seconds that I do not want. I load the data as soon as I get it from the server. the tableview does its thing and I expect  the view to show immediatly after the willDisplayCell is called. the problem is that it  does not show the table immediately and I have to wait 20-50 seconds to see the data.

Comment: reloading tableview data is not animatable, so take the reload code out of the animation block.  Really, just delete the whole animation block and put the reload method call directly into the dispatch block.

Comment: I changed to the following dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView reloadData];
  });
I still get the same effect.

Comment: How many data tasks are fetching?  Are you calling reloadData after **each one** completes or only after **all of them** complete?  With 10 cells, with server data for each, I suspect you're calling `reloadData` 10 times, and network latency is your culprit.

Also, once you `dispatch_async` to main, you're back in contention with all the other things on the main thread that are vying for service, including all of the underlying UIKit/Core Animation/Core Graphics system work, so you might try running the Time Profile instrument to see what's being executed during this delay.

Comment: I think I found the problem. I had a spinner on top of the tableview and seems like it took 50 seconds to dissmiss. It now loads immediatle since I changed     self.loadingView.hidden = NO; to      self.loadingView.hidden = YES;     Thanks for your attention and help. I still do not understand why it takes so long to not show a view.